# Can we rename the [mgs-5-online] tag to [metal-gear-online-3]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-rename-request

[***As per comments below - I've suggested a tag synonym***](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mgs-5-online/synonyms)

I understand that this tag is currently as it is due to it being the online portion of to Metal Gear Solid V, but it's actual title of this portion of the game is **Metal Gear Online 3**.

Would it not be a good idea for the game's tag match the game's title?

[metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Metal_Gear_Online_3](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Metal_Gear_Online_3)

[image]

Comment: Where has it been referred to my Metal Gear Online 3 as the official title? I don't play it, but I haven't seen that title floating around. I have seen Metal Gear Online, however, so maybe it's just the more common name for it?

Comment: @DangerZone Metal Gear Online (or MGO) is the more common title. It's the 3rd iteration of MGO - The 3 red lines that make up the last 'E' in the logo is to signify the 3.

Comment: Gotcha. That's what I assumed. Haven't been a huge fan of online games lately so I haven't had any urge to play it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally, I don't think it's a good idea to outright change the tag to [metal-gear-online-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-online-3) from what has come to be known as the more common title: [mgs-5-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-5-online).

However, I would definitely see benefit to adding a synonym tag. That way, we get the benefits of the more common name, combined with the official name of the game.

Comment: I'd be happy with this solution too :)

Comment: I've got enough rep to suggest a synonym, but it won't let me as it "doesn't exist on the system" - Does this need to be done by someone with higher rep?

Comment: @LoboDemon, I'm an idiot. A question has to exist with that tag first. Without looking, I'm assuming some MGO questions are yours. If you add a new tag alongside the existing one, you can then propose the new tag as a synonym. I did this last week with mgs-5-the-phantom-pain and metal-gear-solid-5 (new) and proposed the second as a synonym.

Comment: Have updated one of my questions and have suggested the synonym

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mgs-5-online/synonyms

Comment: @LoboDemon I've approved this synonym.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the tag's name is [metal-gear-solid-5-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-online), with a synonym of [metal-gear-online-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-online-3). This seems to be backwards if we look at our general policy of always using the game's official title as the tag whenever possible.

Therefore, I think the tag and synonym should be swapped, making [metal-gear-online-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-online-3) the actual tag. A synonym with the more common name is pretty much the intended usage of synonyms as a whole.